# h2o in R - does not give command prompt

Tags: r, h2o

I have tried to follow steps in [this](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/tutorials/gbm/gbmTuning.Rmd) tutorial to install and start `h2o` in R and got here:

```
> h2o.init(nthreads=-1)

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /home/pal/tmp/Rtmp8q7r3M/h2o_pal_started_from_r.out
    /home/pal/tmp/Rtmp8q7r3M/h2o_pal_started_from_r.err

java version "1.8.0-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-ea-b114)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b56, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ... Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         3 seconds 258 milliseconds 
    H2O cluster version:        3.8.2.8 
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_pal_hmx971 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   19.13 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    44 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  44 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    R Version:                  R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
```

However, after this I do not see the usual `>` so that I can start type commands, it is stalled at this point. Do you have any ideas what to do?
The log files: `.err` is empty, `.out` looks like this:

```
06-09 10:31:27.590 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: ----- H2O started  -----
06-09 10:31:27.680 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Build git branch: rel-turchin
06-09 10:31:27.680 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Build git hash: df8dd4c342aa5b1af1fc19b1510c361bcc8af0c4
06-09 10:31:27.681 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Build git describe: jenkins-rel-turchin-8
06-09 10:31:27.681 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Build project version: 3.8.2.8
06-09 10:31:27.681 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Built by: 'jenkins'
06-09 10:31:27.681 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Built on: '2016-06-02 18:35:57'
06-09 10:31:27.682 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Java availableProcessors: 44
06-09 10:31:27.682 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Java heap totalMemory: 1.29 GB
06-09 10:31:27.682 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Java heap maxMemory: 19.13 GB
06-09 10:31:27.682 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Java version: Java 1.8.0-ea (from Oracle Corporation)
06-09 10:31:27.683 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: JVM launch parameters: [-ea]
06-09 10:31:27.683 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: OS version: Linux 3.5.0-39-generic (amd64)
06-09 10:31:27.683 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Machine physical memory: 86.09 GB
06-09 10:31:27.683 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: X-h2o-cluster-id: 1465461085307
06-09 10:31:27.684 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: User name: 'pal'
06-09 10:31:27.684 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: eth1 (eth1), fe80:0:0:0:216:3eff:fe11:2231%eth1
06-09 10:31:27.684 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: eth1 (eth1), 192.168.112.231
06-09 10:31:27.684 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: eth0 (eth0), fe80:0:0:0:216:3eff:fe21:8231%eth0
06-09 10:31:27.685 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: eth0 (eth0), 193.6.218.231
06-09 10:31:27.685 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo
06-09 10:31:27.685 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 127.0.0.1
06-09 10:31:27.685 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Selected H2O.CLOUD_MULTICAST_IF: name:lo (lo) doesn't support multicast
06-09 10:31:27.702 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Internal communication uses port: 54322
06-09 10:31:27.702 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Listening for HTTP and REST traffic on http://127.0.0.1:54321/
06-09 10:31:27.703 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: H2O cloud name: 'H2O_started_from_R_pal_hmx971' on /127.0.0.1:54321, discovery address /238.86.237.46:61014
06-09 10:31:27.704 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: If you have trouble connecting, try SSH tunneling from your local machine (e.g., via port 55555):
06-09 10:31:27.704 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO:   1. Open a terminal and run 'ssh -L 55555:localhost:54321 pal@127.0.0.1'
06-09 10:31:27.704 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO:   2. Point your browser to http://localhost:55555
06-09 10:31:27.704 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Log dir: '/home/pal/tmp/Rtmp8q7r3M/h2ologs'
06-09 10:31:27.704 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Cur dir: '/home/pal'
06-09 10:31:27.735 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: HDFS subsystem successfully initialized
06-09 10:31:27.736 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: S3 subsystem successfully initialized
06-09 10:31:27.736 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Flow dir: '/home/pal/h2oflows'
06-09 10:31:27.758 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Cloud of size 1 formed [/127.0.0.1:54321]
06-09 10:31:27.760 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Registered 0 extensions in: 1058mS
06-09 10:31:28.787 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Registered: 124 REST APIs in: 1026mS
06-09 10:31:29.560 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Registered: 193 schemas in: 773mS
06-09 10:31:29.561 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: 
06-09 10:31:29.561 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: Open H2O Flow in your web browser: http://127.0.0.1:54321/
06-09 10:31:29.561 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  main      INFO: 
06-09 10:31:29.617 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  #31393-25 INFO: Method: GET   , URI: /, route: , parms: {}
06-09 10:31:29.642 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  #31393-26 INFO: Method: GET   , URI: /, route: , parms: {}
06-09 10:31:29.655 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  #31393-27 INFO: Method: GET   , URI: /, route: , parms: {}
06-09 10:31:29.852 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  #31393-31 INFO: Method: GET   , URI: /3/InitID, route: /3/InitID, parms: {}
06-09 10:31:29.854 127.0.0.1:54321       14772  #31393-31 INFO: Locking cloud to new members, because water.api.InitIDV3
```

I am running this on a server without any graphical interface.

Comment: Not reproducible with R 3.3.0. So try to update your R version.

Comment: The tutorial uses the exact same R version as in my example.

Comment: What do you have in the two log files?